# How to customise bottom navigation bar item instead of creating custom Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following below bottom navigation bar code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: cubit.currentIndex,
            onTap: (index) {
              cubit.changeBottomNavIndex(index);
            },
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Home), label: 'Home'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Chat), label: 'Chat'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Paper_Upload,), label: 'Post'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Location), label: 'Location'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Setting), label: 'Settings'),
            ],
          ),
```

and this is the below image:

[image]

So I wonder that if there's a way to customise the middle `bottom navigation bar item` only, instead of creating a custom `Navigation bottom bar` as to be looks like a `Floating action button`...

or I shall create a new customised one?

I hope someone could help me :)...

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of custom made widget our there regarding bottom navigation bar. You can use [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) that has a style that match yours [image: demo]

Comment: thanks a lot I just want to use the default `BottomNavBar` for flutter :).. anyways I have solved a little bit by the previous answer by following this link :) https://codewithandrea.com/articles/bottom-bar-navigation-with-fab/

Comment: yeah a little custom class there, but that's good enough :)

Comment: @ AlannMaulana huh I forgot to add the `floatingActionButtonLocation` property in scaffold :), I just edited my answer ty between for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I think it's not the best one:

just add a floating action button as the below code :

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () { },
            tooltip: 'Post',
            child: Icon(IconBroken.Paper_Upload, color: Colors.white,),
            elevation: 2.0,
          ),
```

and added the below line in the `Scaffold` Part:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
```

as it's shows as the below image:

[image]

but I see it's not looks good..

I hope someone gives me better answer :)